# How to retain multiple fields filled after POST?

Tags: php, post

I have a title/entry form for submitting a blog post. On submit, it checks for the same title in the db (which you're not allowed to do), then returns an error to tell you to change your title. I want it to keep both fields filled after the POST, because duh, a user shouldn't have to rewrite the entire entry. However, it only keeps the TITLE. session_start exists in the header.php. Please ignore any SQL injection vulnerable sections.

```
<?php
require("connect.php");
require("header.php");
if(isset($_POST['post'])){
$title = $_POST['blogtitle'];
$entry = $_POST['blogentry'];
$author = $_SESSION['username'];
$newBlogPostQuery = "SELECT * FROM contents WHERE title='$title'";
$newBlogPostResult = mysqli_query($conn, $newBlogPostQuery) or die("Error:".mysqli_error($conn));
$newBlogPostRow = mysqli_fetch_array($newBlogPostResult, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

if(mysqli_num_rows($newBlogPostResult) ==1){
    $blogPostExists = TRUE;
}
else{
    $blogQuery = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO contents (timestamp, title, entry, authorName) VALUES (now(), '$title', '$entry', '$author')");
    if($blogQuery){
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
}
}

?>
<div class="flex-enable flex-center blog-body">
<?php if(isset($blogPostExists)&&$blogPostExists){
                echo '<div class="exception" style="margin: 0;"><span class="small-white-subtitle">Please use a different title.</div>';
            }
            ?>
    <form class="flex-enable flex-column" method="POST">
        <label for="blogtitle"><span class="blog-insert-title">Title</span></label>
        <input class="blog-input-text small-white-title" id="blogtitle" type="text" name="blogtitle" placeholder="Your title" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['blogtitle']) ? $_POST['blogtitle']:''; ?>">
        <label for="blogentry"><span class="blog-insert-title">Blog post</span></label>
        <textarea class="blog-input-text blog-insert-entry" id="blogentry" type="text" rows="20" name="blogentry" placeholder="Write something amazing here..." value="<?php echo isset($_POST['blogentry']) ? $_POST['blogentry']:''; ?>"></textarea>
        <input class="form-button small-white-title" type="submit" name="post" value="Post">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: *Please ignore any SQL injection vulnerable sections* - they should never be ignored!

Comment: I'm doing a uni assignment, and solving those isn't a requirement (so far). I'm all for good coding practices, but only after necessary functionality is achieved.

Comment: If I'm you lecturer, I would make this an requirement to solve the task - seems like they teach you to build insecure web apps..

Comment: On point. I still have to understand what is being taught. If it weren't for SO, I'd still struggle with echo "Hello World";

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Textarea` has no `value` attribute, the content is between `<textarea>` and `</textarea>`.

```
<textarea class="blog-input-text blog-insert-entry" id="blogentry" type="text" rows="20" name="blogentry" placeholder="Write something amazing here..."><?php echo isset($_POST['blogentry']) ? htmlentities($_POST['blogentry']) : ''; ?></textarea>
```

Comment: In addition to that, you should use `htmlentities`

Comment: @Philipp: you're right, I've added it there. The main point wasn't in escaping, but in HTML and invalid `value` attribute for `textarea`.

Comment: I would have never thought to look up textarea attributes. Might need to freshen up on that html. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You shoul put the value beetween textarea tags

```
<textarea class="blog-input-text blog-insert-entry" id="blogentry" type="text" rows="20" name="blogentry" placeholder="Write something amazing here..." ><?php echo isset($_POST['blogentry']) ? $_POST['blogentry']:''; ?></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put value between textarea start and end tag Your Value

in your case, it will be

```
    <textarea class="blog-input-text blog-insert-entry" id="blogentry" type="text" rows="20" name="blogentry" placeholder="Write something amazing here..."><?php echo isset($_POST['blogentry']) ? $_POST['blogentry']:''; ?></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

Textarea has no value attribute

```
<form class="flex-enable flex-column" method="POST">
    <label for="blogtitle"><span class="blog-insert-title">Title</span></label>
    <input class="blog-input-text small-white-title" id="blogtitle" type="text" name="blogtitle" placeholder="Your title" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['post'])){ echo $_POST['blogtitle']; } ?>">
    <label for="blogentry"><span class="blog-insert-title">Blog post</span></label>
    <textarea class="blog-input-text blog-insert-entry" id="blogentry" type="text" rows="20" name="blogentry" placeholder="Write something amazing here..." value="<?php if(isset($_POST['post'])){ echo $_POST['blogentry']; } ?>"></textarea>
    <input class="form-button small-white-title" type="submit" name="post" value="Post">
```